# Nifi Publish Amqp to RabbitMQ Malformed data error

Tags: apache-nifi, amqp, processor

I have 2 processors one of them is "**ConsumeAmqp**" that consume from rabbit successfully, other is "PublishAmqp" that is get the consume data and push another queue.

[image]

How can passing data that consuming header and body from ConsumeAMQP processors to Publish AMQP processors?

I tried to create new attribute name as header, and payload but I can not fill the data with consuming.

**My updateAttribute like this but not work it.**
[image]

Error is like that "
*PublishAMQP[id=1759fd41-0178-1000-23fe-815361cddee2] Malformed key value pair for AMQP header property: {}"*

Comment: If you pause your flow and open one of the flow files, you'll see that 'amqp$headers' attribute already exists as it's written by ConsumeAMQP. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the UpdateAttribute - you're just making a copy of existing attributes. Also, the error is from the PublishAMQP processor, not from the UpdateAttribute, so need more details to clarify what isn't working & what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have a flow that has a DB connection if it can not persist the data to DB, I want to push back the initial amqp to queue. So updateAttribute just refer to all DB persist task in this picture. Also I checked the queue and data was pushed but already publishAMQP processor gives error like above. Probably I can not set the header part of the processor. How can set the publishAmqpProcessro header part? because my header that incoming ampq also empty. Do you have any ideal...